# If $gf$ is an equalizer , is $f$ an equalizer?

Tags: category-theory

Suppose $gf$ is an equalizer in a category $\mathfrak C$, I think that $f$ not necessarly is an equalizer, but I don't know how to come up with a counterexample; i've really tried it so hard. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*(Third time's the charm? -- old wrong answer left deleted because its comments don't apply here)*

Consider the following category with objects $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$.

```
1 --s--> 2 --f--> 3 --g--> 4 --p--> 5
  -------h------>            --q-->
```

There's an arrow $n\to m$ whenever $n\le m$, and these arrows are unique except for the following cases:

- $fs \ne h: 1\to 3$
- $p \ne q: 4\to5$
- $pg \ne qg : 3 \to 5$

Then $gf$ is an equalizer of $p$ and $q$, as seen by inspecting all arrows that end at $4$:

- $g$ and $\mathrm{id}_4$ are out because $pg\ne qg$.
- $gf$ is the equalizer itself.
- $gfs$ satisfies $p(gfs)=q(gfs)$. It factors through $gf$ as it should, and the mediating arrow $s$ is trivially unique.
- $gh$ is the same arrow as $gfs$.

However, $f$ is not an equalizer. In particular it is not an equalizer of $pg$ and $qg$ because $(pg)h=(qg)h$ yet $h$ does not factor through $f$.

Comment: 1+. Thanks for providing the answer which my comment refers to ;). One also has to check that your category is, indeed, a category. This is not completely trivial, because essentially it means to find a normal form of a certain category defined by generators and relations.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg: Is there anything to check but associativity? That is trivial here because every $a\circ b\circ c$ either involves an identity or is so long that its result belongs to a hom-set that I've defined to be a singleton.

Comment: Yes, you're right.

Answer (score 5):

In many cases this property of [regular monomorphisms](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/regular+monomorphism) actually holds.

1. A trivial but already quite large class of examples is where every monomorphism is regular.
2. If $gf$ is a regular monomorphism and $g$ is a monomorphism, then $f$ is a regular monomorphism. Namely, if $gf$ is the equalizer of $u,v$, then one can check that $f$ is the equalizer of $ug,vg$.
3. If $gf$ is a [strong monomorphism](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/strong+monomorphism), then also $f$ is a strong monomorphism. This is an easy observation, a proof can be found in Borceux, *Handbook of categorical algebra*, Volume 1, Proposition 4.6.5 (2).
4. Every regular epimorphism is strong (loc. cit., part (4) of that Proposition). The converse holds in every [regular](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/regular+category) category: Borceux, *Handbook of categorical algebra*, Volume 2, Proposition 2.1.4.

Hence, in a coregular category (= dual to a regular category), regular monomorphisms coincide with strong monomorphisms, which implies the desired property. Besides from existence of certain (co)limits, a category is coregular when regular monomorphisms are universal, i.e. if $A \hookrightarrow B$ is a regular monomorphism and $A \to C$ is an arbitrary morphism ("cobase change"), then also $C \to B \cup_A C$ is a regular monomorphism. There are lots of examples, for example $\mathsf{Set}$, $\mathsf{Top}$, $\mathsf{Haus}$ abelian categories, and $\mathsf{Ban}_1$. Is $\mathsf{Grp}$ is coregular?

What makes me wonder is that Proposition 6.4 in the paper Adhesive and quasiadhesive categories by Stephen Lack and Pawel Sobicinski reads: "The following hold in any category C: (i) if mn is a regular monomorphism and m is arbitrary then n is a regular monomorphism;" I think that Henning's counterexample shows that this is wrong.

---

**Addendum**. The following lemma often appears in the foundations of algebraic geometry, but it is also useful here.

*Lemma*. Let $P$ be a class of morphisms in a category with pullbacks which is stable under pullbacks and composition. Also assume that every diagonal morphism $Y \to Y \times_S Y$ lies in $P$. Then $gf \in P$ implies $f \in P$ (*cancellation property*).

*Proof*. Write $X \xrightarrow{f} Y \xrightarrow{g} S$ and factor $f$ as $X \xrightarrow{\Gamma_f} X \times_S Y \xrightarrow{\mathrm{pr}_2} Y$. Here, $\Gamma_f$ is a pullback of the diagonal $Y \to Y \times_S Y$, and $\mathrm{pr}_1$ is a pullback of $X \to S$. Both are in $P$. $\square$

In a category, regular monomorphisms are always stable under pullbacks (*Handbook*, Vol. 1, Prop. 4.3.8 (2)), and split monomorphisms are always regular. This proves:

*Corollary.* In a category with pullbacks such that regular monomorphisms are closed under composition, the regular monomorphisms satisfy the cancellation property.

This applies to a large class of categories, among of which are coregular categories, but many more.

Comment: Adamek-Herrlich-Strecker, [Abstract and Concrete Categories](http://katmat.math.uni-bremen.de/acc/), have some examples. In the exercises to section 7 they ask the reader to verify examples showing that: **(7J)** in the category of functionally Hausdorff spaces, regular monomorphisms are not closed under composition and $gf$ regular monic does not imply $f$ regular monic; dually **(7S)** in $\mathsf{Cat}$ regular epis are not closed under composition and $gf$ regular epi does not imply $g$ regular epi. (I didn't check the details myself)

Comment: Why not adding this as an answer? This is not a comment to my answer, it is an answer.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg How can I see, whether the category of groups *is* coregular?