# Is the category of topological spaces coregular?

Tags: general-topology, category-theory

Everything is in the title. The category Top of topological spaces and continuous mappings is not regular, but is it coregular ? Furthermore, Top isn't cartesian closed, but does it satisfy the dual of cartesian-closedness ?

Comment: According to nlab, any cocartesian closed category is equivalent to the terminal category, which $\mathbf{Top}$ is certainly not.

Comment: And according to this MSE answer: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/301753/36404 $\mathbf{Top}$ is coregular.

Comment: The dual of "cartesian closed" is not "cocartesian closed" but "cocartesian coclosed" (in nLab). A cocartesian coclosed category is a category C with finite colimits in which, for any two objects A and B, there exists a "coexponent" coexp(A,B) such that C(coexp(A,B),C) is isomorphic to C(B,A+C), where + is the coproduct. The dual of any Heyting algebra is already a cocartesian coclosed category, since a Heyting algebra is a cartesian closed poset. But such a dual is not the terminal category...

Comment: There's no chance of $\mathbf{Top}$ being cocartesian coclosed: if it were, then we would have $X + (Y \times Z) \cong (X + Y) \times (X + Z)$, which is not even true for numbers.

Comment: Well then, chosing $C=*$ the one-point space, we'd have $\mathbf{Top}(\operatorname{coexp}(A,B),*) \cong \mathbf{Top}(B,A\coprod *)$ for any pair of topological spaces $A$, $B$. Which isn't true for any choice of $\operatorname{coexp}(A,B)$